# Text color overlay in FabricJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to create an effect in FabricJS, where the color of some text I am adding to my canvas is determined by a texture. Should be easy, but when I apply the texture as a pattern, I cannot work out the combination of scale, rotation etc that I need to make it work. It appears to me like the pattern is being applied 'local' to the object, so (0,0), is the object's top left coords, rather than that of the overall image.

So if here's my text color texture,

[image]

and I placed some text in the middle, the effect I want would be this:

[image]

I've tried various things with static canvas etc, but I've hit a dead end. Please can someone help? Here's my current attempt:

```
var patternSourceCanvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas();

    oImg.setAngle(-angles[i]);

    patternSourceCanvas.add(oImg);

    var pattern = new fabric.Pattern({
      source: function() {

       patternSourceCanvas.setDimensions({
          width: oImg.getWidth(),
          height: oImg.getHeight()
        });

        return patternSourceCanvas.getElement();
      },
      repeat: 'no-repeat'
    });


    var text = new fabric.Text(entry, {
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
      left: (coords[i][0] * bufWidth),
      top: (coords[i][1] * bufHeight),
      fill: pattern,
      centeredRotation: true,
      angle: angles[i],
      fontFamily: 'Kapra',
      fontSize: 42
    });
```

Huge thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got this idea, you can obtain the effect using the globalCompositeOperation property of fabricJs objects

[image]

```
// clear canvas
canvas.clear();

    var text = new fabric.Text('AAAAA', {
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
      left:30,
      top: 30,
      fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
      centeredRotation: true,
      angle: 20,
      fontSize: 100,
    });
canvas.add(text);
fabric.Image.fromURL('../assets/pug.jpg', function(oImg) { 
  oImg.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
  oImg.width = canvas.width;
  oImg.heigth = canvas.height;
  canvas.add(oImg);
  var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    globalCompositeOperation: 'destination-over',
    fill: 'black'
  });
  canvas.add(rect);   
});
```

So basically you render the text in any color, black.
Then you render the color image OVER the text, covering all the canvas, specifying `globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop'`

After this you have a colored text on a white background.
To have a black background now draw a rect big as the canvas, but specify `globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over'`

So you will do something totally different but it will work.
May need tweaking and may not fit your needs. But it should show the example you posted.

Comment: I just tried to export that canvas in SVG but is not working.